# How can I know if 2 buttons are pressed? JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, button, javafx, actionevent

I have got a GridPane with 10x10 Buttons. All placed in an ArrayList called 'buttons'. Now I need to know that, when a button is clicked, it should remember that one and when another button is clicked perform an action. So you will get like a method 
       makeTurn(Button 1, Button 2); 
Now's my question, how do I do this? Here is my first class where I make the GUI

```
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Labeled;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;




public class DamspelApp  extends Application implements      EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
private ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
private Damspel spel = new Damspel();





@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
//CREATING UPPER HBOX
    Label melding = new Label(""+spel.getMeldingProperty());
    if(spel.getMelding()==null){
        melding.setText("Hier komen de meldingen!");
    }
    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    hbox.getChildren().add(melding);
    hbox.setPrefHeight(40);
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

 //CREATING HBOX
    Button reset = new Button("reset");
    reset.setPrefWidth(60);
    CheckBox roteren = new CheckBox();
    roteren.getStyleClass().add("roteren");
    Label rot = new Label("Bord roteren");
    Label speler_lb = new Label("Speler: " + spel.getSpelerProperty());
    Label stenenZ_lb = new Label("Stenen Z: ");
    Label stenenW_lb = new Label("Stenen W: ");
//CREATING VBOX 
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().add(reset);
    HBox hbxo = new HBox();
    hbxo.getChildren().add(roteren);
    hbxo.getChildren().add(rot);
    vbox.getChildren().add(hbxo);
    vbox.getChildren().add(speler_lb);
    vbox.getChildren().add(stenenZ_lb);
    vbox.getChildren().add(stenenW_lb);
    vbox.setSpacing(10);
    vbox.setPrefWidth(100);


//CREATING AND POSITIONING IN BORDERPANE        
    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();     
    border.setCenter(grid);
    border.setTop(hbox);
    border.setLeft(vbox);   

 //CREATING THE BUTTONS     
    int columns = 1;
    int rows=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        buttons.add(new Button(""+i));
    }
    for(Button b : buttons){
        grid.add(b, columns, rows);
        String text = b.getText();
        int texti = Integer.parseInt(text);
        columns++;
        b.setId(text);
        b.setPrefSize(45,45);
        b.setOnAction(this);
        if(texti == 9 || texti == 19||texti==29||texti==39||texti==49||texti==59||texti==69||texti==79||texti==89||texti==99){
            rows++;
            columns = 1;
        }

        String cssClassVoorButton = spel.getVeldStatus(texti);
            switch(cssClassVoorButton){
            case "WITDAM":b.getStyleClass().add("witdam");break;
            case "ZWARTDAM": b.getStyleClass().add("zwartdam");break;
            case "WIT": b.getStyleClass().add("wit");break;
            case "ZWART": b.getStyleClass().add("zwart"); break;
            case "NIETSPEELBAAR":    b.getStyleClass().add("nietspeelbaar");break;
            case "LEEG": b.getStyleClass().add("leeg");break;
            default: break;
            }
    }

 //MAKING THE SCENE
    Scene scene = new Scene(border, 500, 500);
    //File cssSheet = new File("myCSS.css");
    //scene.getStylesheets().add(cssSheet.toURI().toString());
    scene.getStylesheets().add("stylesheet2.css");
    primaryStage.setTitle("Kamer Boeken");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Rotate-RESET     
    reset.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(3000), grid);
            rt.setByAngle(180);
            rt.setCycleCount(1);
            rt.setAutoReverse(false);
            rt.play();
        }
    });



    if(roteren.isSelected() && spel.getCheck()){
        RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(3000), grid);
        rt.setByAngle(180);
        rt.setCycleCount(1);
        rt.setAutoReverse(false);
    }

}
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println(""+ event.getSource());
    for(Button b : buttons){
        if(event.getSource() == b){
            System.out.println(""+ event.getSource());
            b.getStyleClass().add("leeg");
            String styleclass = spel.getVeldStatus(Integer.parseInt(b.getText()));
            String stylec = styleclass.toLowerCase();
            b.getStyleClass().remove(stylec);
            System.out.println(spel.getVeldStatus(Integer.parseInt(b.getText())));

        }
    }

}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Application.launch(args);
}


}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by this ? Can you explain your motive, so that we can help you accordingly? Your question doesn't explain much, neither does your code.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is a game of checkers. So if I press one button, it should highlight all the possible options, and if one of the options is clicked, it should create a turn with the method createTurn(Button 1, Button 2) in another class. But if the same button is clicked twice, it should de-highlight it.     When the creatTurn method is called, the StyleClass of the button with a picture on it will become empty, and the empty button will become the one with a image on it.

Comment: This is more of a logical problem. I have a solution (may be not the best one). Why not keep a universal button reference and call it `activeButton`. Whenever a button, is clicked, the first thing that it does is check if the activeButton holds `null` reference. If yes, highlight all the possible options and assign it to the button which has just been clicked. Next time, when someone clicks, it checks for activeButton, this time it is not null, it doesn't highlight possible checks but calls `createTurn()` and assigns null to it. If the reference are same, `un-hilighted` and assign `null`.

Comment: `ToggleButton` as suggested by @eckig, provides a better approach to the whole problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to store the first `Button` that was clicked somewhere. And additionally I would recommend to use `ToggleButton`s, as the user can more clearly see which `Button` was pressed:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private final ObjectProperty<ToggleButton> rememberMe = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final List<ToggleButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(5);
        grid.setVgap(5);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(row + " | " + col);

                button.selectedProperty().addListener((w, o, n) -> {
                    if (n) {
                        if(rememberMe.get() != null) {
                            turn(rememberMe.get() , button);
                        }
                        else {
                            rememberMe.set(button);
                        }
                    }
                });
                grid.add(button, col, row);
                buttons.add(button);
            }
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void turn(ToggleButton pButton1, ToggleButton pButton2) {
        rememberMe.set(null);

        System.out.println(pButton1 + " - " + pButton2);

        buttons.forEach(tb -> tb.setSelected(false));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

From here on, creating the highlighting and the rest of your games logic should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Curiosity question: What's the difference between using a ToggleButton variable and using a ToggleButton ObjectProperty, i. e. is there any benefit in this case?

Comment: @Roland In this case: No difference at all. I just kept it from an earlier version of this answer where I used Bindings.

Comment: Thanks I still sticked to the normal Button but the part of your rememberMe array is really helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Node's methods [setUserData](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData%28java.lang.Object%29) and [getUserData](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getUserData%28%29) to store various information like whether you clicked a button or not.

As an alternative you could use a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) to store a boolean state.